# Check for condition in GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

Take this example data:

```
ID    Status    Date
1     Pending   2/10/2020
2     Pending   2/10/2020
3     Pending   2/10/2020
2     Pending   2/10/2020
2     Pending   2/10/2020
1     Complete  2/15/2020
```

I need an SQL statement that will group all the data but bring back the current status. So for ID 1 the group by needs a condition that only returns the Completed row and also returned the pending rows for ID 2 and 3.

I am not 100% how to write in the condition for this.

Maybe something like:

```
SELECT ID, Status, Date
FROM table
GROUP BY ID, Status, Date
ORDER BY ID
```

The problem with this is the resulting data would look like:

```
ID    Status    Date
1     Pending   2/10/2020
1     Complete  2/15/2020
2     Pending   2/10/2020
3     Pending   2/10/2020
```

But I need:

```
ID    Status    Date
1     Complete  2/15/2020
2     Pending   2/10/2020
3     Pending   2/10/2020
```

What can I do to check for the Completed status so I can only return Completed in the group by?

Comment: What determines what the current row is? Could something go back to `'Pending'` after being `'Complete'`?

Comment: Why is ID 1 "Complete"? This is implying some sort of order but there is nothing in your data to indicate order.

Comment: The table is being updated with many more fields but it all comes down to if the latest data shows completed status. The rows in the table are not being updated to the new status but rather the system is just adding new rows with the new status.

Comment: @Mike-SMT . . . And how do you know what the "latest data" is?  You have no indication of a time or ordering column in the data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff there is a timestamp for when the row was added. I can add that into my example for clarity.

Comment: Can an ID ever go from Complete to Pending status?

Comment: If there is a timestamp (do you mean `rowversion` or a date and time, they are *very* different) then you should be telling us about that, yes.

Comment: @jarlh I am not sure that might be a possibility. I would have to check with the team that works with that data. For now lets assume not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Date as 'last row indicator', you can:

```
DECLARE @Src TABLE (
    ID int,
    Status varchar(20),
    Date Date
)

INSERT @Src VALUES
(1, 'Pending' ,'2/10/2020'),
(1, 'Complete' ,'2/15/2020'),
(2, 'Pending' ,'2/10/2020'),
(3, 'Pending' ,'2/10/2020');

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM @Src
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC)
```

Result:

```
ID          Status               Date
----------- -------------------- ----------
1           Complete             2020-02-15
2           Pending              2020-02-10
3           Pending              2020-02-10
```

Comment: This is interesting. You are using things I have not actually seen before. Like `PARTITION BY`. I will have to take a closer look at your example when I get a chance to test it on my end.

Comment: What exactly is the `WITH TIES` part? I have not seen `TIES` before.

Comment: @Mike-SMT You can find what 're you looking for [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) & [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: It looks like I can get the same results using `SELECT ID, MIN([Status]), MAX([Date])
FROM @Src
group by ID` So what option is better? Or does it even matter?

Comment: After testing `min()`, `max()` and your example I think your example is more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Do only `GROUP BY` the ID column. Use `MIN()` to chose Complete before Pending.

```
SELECT ID, MIN(Status)
FROM table
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Yes, @Mike-SMT .

Comment: This works for the super simplified sample but if they ever add another status that would sort earlier than "Complete" this will no longer work. Hopefully they have something better to use for order of the status values.

Comment: @SeanLange well I did simplify a lot but the status will only ever be one of 2 values.

Comment: @Mike-SMT that is how the system works today perhaps. But what about in 3 years when somebody else adds a status and suddenly your code is broken? Use actual data to indicate the correct order. Like a date column in your table.

Comment: @SeanLange If that changes then I will have to update my query but it has been one of 2 values for 10 years so I do not think it will change any time soon.

Comment: But why not make it right from the get go? It seems from the comments you have a datetime column in the table. Get top 1 ordered by that. And then no matter what happens down the road your code will always get the current value.

Comment: @SeanLange that makes sense.